# Running everything using transactions in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

Been working on a couple of `Connection` classes for `C#` data `CRUD` ops for a couple of days and have been thinking, normally I use a flag to turn on and off the transactions when creating the class, what happens if I use transactions for every non-query i execute? Any advantages of disadvantages i should be aware of?

Comment: what is " non-query " ?

Comment: Besides holding locks slightly longer, I can't really see an obvious downside.

Comment: ["Non-query"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) should mean update/insert/delete/... that don't return results.

Comment: it means it doesn't return a query...

Answer (score 0):

Long transaction are locking tables, so It's not preferable to do everything in transaction, especially very long running operations, because it can kill your database.

for more info read this:
http://simononsoftware.com/are-long-running-transactions-bad/

Comment: First, if you're locking tables, you're probably handling transactions incorrectly. Second, on most (all?) modern SQL dbms, [every SQL update executes within a transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174377%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can write a whole big book about transactions, it's advantages and disadvantages. But the main idea is: unless you handle a biiiiiig databases for big corporations, just DO use transactions ;)